# C# multi-player socket server (need clarification/suggestions)

Tags: c#, multiplayer, client-server, multithreading, socket

I've been working on an 2D-RPG for a while and I recently decided to make it into an MMO (not really massive, but multi-player). Anyways, I'm attempting to write a game server in C#. Yes, I know I could use a commercial solution like SmartFoxServer or Photon, but I want to make it a learning curve by going through the pain of doing it myself. It's pretty much going to be a simple zone-room architecture that handles events and sends position updates a few times in a second.

A lot of articles I read recommended using UDP but I'm limited to TCP because my client will be a browser based flash file. I've pretty much worked out in my head how I want everything to work, the binary protocol and etc, but I'm stuck at the beginning.

I'm not quite sure how to start. I've read about 3 different types of socket communication in C#:

1. **Blocking** - I know I can't use this because the main thread will be blocked when accepting connections and etc.
2. **Non-Blocking**
3. **Asynchronous**

I don't know which is the better, or the obvious choice for what I'm trying to do. I want the server to be scalable and handle a few hundred concurrent connections. I tried to study SFS and it seemed like it had multiple thread pools, for accepting connections, receiving data and sending data respectively. I had it in my mind that I would do it the same way and use the ThreadPool class, but I'm not sure of the difference between non-blocking and asynchronous.

Can someone clarify to me the difference between the two and which one is the better choice for me. I would appreciate any link you think might help as well.

Answer (score 1):

Non-blocking is basically the same thing as asynchronous: if you use the async features of .Net sockets you will get non-blocking code for free.

I doubt you are using C# 4.5 so you will need to resort to the 'older' way of doing non-blocking IO. The following is a snippet which deals with how to stream data from a TCP connection (you will likely want to use UDP, but the core principles are the same):

```
private Socket _socket;
private ArraySegment<byte> _buffer;
public void StartReceive()
{
    ReceiveAsyncLoop(null);
}

// Note that this method is not guaranteed (in fact
// unlikely) to remain on a single thread across
// async invocations.
private void ReceiveAsyncLoop(IAsyncResult result)
{
    try
    {
        if (result != null)
        {
            int numberOfBytesRead = _socket.EndReceive(result);
            if(numberOfBytesRead == 0)
            {
                OnDisconnected(null); // 'null' being the exception. The client disconnected normally in this case.
                return;
            }

            var newSegment = new ArraySegment<byte>(_buffer.Array, _buffer.Offset, numberOfBytesRead);
            OnDataReceived(newSegment);
        }
        _socket.BeginReceive(_buffer.Array, _buffer.Offset, _buffer.Count, SocketFlags.None, ReceiveAsyncLoop, null);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Socket error handling here.
    }
}
```

Also remember that dealing with 100's of users (as opposed to 1000's) is actually pretty easy. If you keep your networking code and your game code on different threads you ***might*** even be able to get away with blocking sockets (non-blocking/async was involved in solving the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html)).

I have a [blog post](http://jonathan.dickinsons.co.za/blog/2011/02/net-sockets-and-you/) on the matter which you might find useful.